# Show that $df_x: TM_x\rightarrow TN_{f(x)}$ is well-defined

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, topological-vector-spaces

Let $f\colon M\rightarrow N$ be a $C^\infty$ function between $C^\infty$ manifolds. Show that $$df_x: TM_x\rightarrow TN_{f(x)}$$ defined by $$df_x([c_0]) := [f \circ c_0]$$ is a well-defined map. Where $[c_0]$ is an equivalence class.

As a side-question; Is it possible to do this without charts? I think my course doesn't use charts

Comment: Assuming $[c_0]$ is an infinitesimal curve, you need to show that if $c_0$ and $c_1$ are two curves in $M$ which are infinitesimally equivalent at $x$, then $df_x([c_0])=df_x([c_1])$.  Recall that $c_0 \sim c_1$ if $(g\circ c_0)'(0)=(g\circ c_1)'(0)$ for all $g \in C^\infty(x)$.